# Merge [genre-trope] into [trope]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[genre-trope](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre-trope) has 8 questions.
[trope](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trope) has 45 questions.

According to its description, a genre trope is a trope that's only applicable to a given genre. Of course, having a Stack dedicated to a cluster of overlapping genres, most, if not all tropes that get asked about will be genre tropes.

Looking at the questions, there doesn't seem to be any difference in subject between the two tags. Therefore, I propose to **merge [genre-trope] into [trope]**.

Comment: Or even get rid of both, as they seem to be largely covered by the more popular `[history-of]` and `[terminology]`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we should. And while we're at it, let's merge [recurring-themes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recurring-themes) into [trope](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trope) (11 questions) too.